# How to separate libraries for main code, test code from each other and apk building in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, apk, buildpath

I recently attempted to add `JUnit` tests to my android service project by adding another "*source folder*" called "`tests`". My "`main`" source folder depends on some `.jar` files that I keep under the `libs` directory and added to project properties, `java build path`, `libraries`.

Now "`tests`" depends on libraries like `junit.jar` but I'd also like to add [accessive.jar](http://code.google.com/p/accessive/wiki/Documentation) to test private methods.

I wish to exclude these new jars, as well as the `tests` source folder, from both building the APK and generally from the build path of the "`main`" source directory, to keep everything clean.

I tried to right-click the "`test`" source folder but couldn't find an applicable setting. I'm using eclipse 4.2.1 with adt.

How do I separate the library settings for the "`main`" and the "`test`" source directory?